# Trouble with bean scopes of @Startup @Singleton and @Produces

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi

I have a class that has to run on startup so I created the following:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Initialization
{

  @Inject
  private InitialDAO dao;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init()
  {
    dao.assurePresenceEngineStructure();
  }
}
```

the InitialDAO has a session that is injected by a Producer method in a seperate class. here is the initalDAO:

```
public class InitialDAO 
{
  @Inject
  protected Session session;

  public void assurePresenceEngineStructure() 
  {
    Node node = session.getNode("/test");
    System.out.println(node.getPath);
  }
}
```

and the class having the producer method:

```
public class SessionProducer
{
    @RequestScoped
    @Produces
    public Session getSession() throws RepositoryException
    { 

      Session session = new FakeSession();
      return session;
    }
}
```

Note that the producer method has been given requestScoped and the singleton is given applicationscoped as described in the ejb spec.

The problem I'm facing is the no active context problem as due to the difference in scoping, the dao will not get a session as the singleton uses a different scope which differs from requestScoped.

I could rewrite all and avoid using the injection, but I was wondering if it is possible to "misuse" the producer method from the singleton in order to get a working initialdao?

regards,

michael

Comment: The problem is not that you inject one scope into another. This is solved by CDI using proxies.

Comment: Hi Adrian, what do you mean that that is not the problem?

Comment: I don't understand the previous comment, but the error you're describing is accurate.  There is no request scope context active during the invocation of a post construct of a singleton EJB.  You can either manually start the context (using DeltaSpike's CDI Control) or produce the session object in a dependent way.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your reply. Could you elaborate a bit about creating a session object in a dependent way?